# What glyph to pick from alternatives in Kēlen script?

Tags: writing-systems

The Kēlen alphabet as given on https://www.terjemar.net/kelen/writing.php shows variants for some letters. Here is an example:

[image: Sample]

Are there rules on when to pick which form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no such rules are mentioned anywhere.

However, [the general orthography page](https://www.terjemar.net/kelen/phono.php) only seems to mention one form for each letter, and those forms are also the only ones I can find in any [Kelen word of the day](http://kelen.conlang.org/archives/category/dict) entry I've looked at - granted, I haven't looked at all that many of them, so I may have missed some that use the alternate forms. It does, however, seem to me like those forms are the only ones in use.